# Cannot connect to open TCP port on remote server

Tags: networking, tcp

On my remote server, I installed `ElasticSearch`, which can be accessed at `http://localhost:9200/`:

[image]

I defined an inbound security rule, `Port9200`, in the firewall for my remote server:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, Port 9200 is publicly accessible to everybody.

When I tried to access the remote `ElasticSearch` server from the browser in my local computer, I saw the following time-out message:

[image]

**My router firewall does not have any rules blocking outbound traffic to any TCP port.**

Any suggestions on how to make my remote ElasticSearch server accessible from my local machine?

**UPDATE 1:** Here are the results after running `netstat -ano | find ":9200"`:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I have updated the relevant configuration file and now these are the new results after running `netstat -ano | find ":9200"`:

[image]

Unfortunately, I still cannot access my remote ElasticSearch server from my local machine.

Comment: Daft question: have you configured the ElasticSearch server to listen to the public IP of the remote server?

Comment: @Attie Apologies if this doesn't answer your question, but here are the ports which are listening (on my remote server): https://pasteboard.co/I6rNtSM.png

Comment: Look ok, that does the "_Scpoe_" tab say? and I presume ts an "_Allow_" rule...?

Comment: @Kinnectus I added these files to my ``elasticsearch.yml`` file: https://pasteboard.co/I6rTkaw.png

Comment: @Attie Here is the ``Scope`` tab: https://pasteboard.co/I6rTWbp.png

Comment: Do you connect to the WAN IP address or the Local IP Address? If your router does not support a loopback connection (likely) then you need the local IP address to connect to the server

Comment: please run (admin cmd prompt): `netstat -ano | find ":9200"` and add the results to the question.

Comment: @HelpingHand Done!

Comment: The process is listening just on 127.0.0.1. It should say 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces or an IP to be externally accessible. I assume there is a config file where you can define the interface the port listens on.

Comment: @HelpingHand Made changes to the relevant config file, updated question again.